# Quotes inside text field of align environment not displaying correctly

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, csquotes

I'm using the package `csquotes` with `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` for quoting in my German paper, but the quoting doesn't seem to work correctly within the text field of an align environment.

Allow me to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
    "This works fine", and so does $\text{"this"}$.
    \begin{equation*}
        \text{and even "this"}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{But somehow "this does not"}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: csquotes does not work inside align environment]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to go about fixing it?

I am writing something that involve functions on strings and I need to use quotations in an `align` environment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After some poking around, it works if you use `\enquote{text}` instead of `"` and expecting `csquote` to autoconvert the quotes.

So the following MWE works and gives the correct output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
    "This works fine", and so does $\text{"this"}$.
    \begin{equation*}
        \text{and even "this"}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{But \enquote{this works now}}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: using enquote works]

I think I'm going to leave the question (and my workaround) here just in case anyone searches for this problem in the future (or if anyone has some insights to share).

Comment: this works, but i'd still like to know why the original fails and how to make it work.